# Use Handlebars data within Laravel's blade template function

Tags: php, laravel, handlebars.js, laravel-blade, mustache

I want to use Handlebars data (i.e. `{{ id }}`) as a parameter in Laravel helper function on .blade template view.

I know about escaping Handlebars brackets when using .blade.php extension like `@{{#each users}}` or `@{{ name }}` and that works perfectly.

The problem comes when I want to use `@{{ id}}` within Laravel's helper function because of nested double curly brackets:

```
<a href="#" class="btn btn-xs btn-warning" data-route="{{ route('admin.membership.toggle-show-hide', ['id' => @{{ id }}]) }}">
    Hide
</a>
```

I know this can't work because helper function `route` doesn't expect curly bracket in parameters array but I still need to be able to pass data from Handlebars contex into Laravel's helper function on blade template view somehow.

I tried different ways to achieve this, but without success.

Does anyone knows some workaround or has any idea for this?
Thank you all in advance.

**EDIT**

The **alternative** (which I currently use) is to write a Handlebars helper which will accept needed parameter and generate route for some action:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper("mmbrshpToggleShowHideRoute", function(id) {
    return APP_URL + '/admin/membership/' + id + '/toggleShowHide';
});
```

Using this, I can generate route string in Handlebars template (with .blade.php extension) for each item in Handlebars JSON context retrieved from Laravel's controller:

```
<a href="#" class="btn btn-xs btn-success" data-route="{{ mmbrshpToggleShowHideRoute id }}">
    Hide
</a>
```

I don't like this approach because I'm actually hardcoding the route URL in Handlebars helper function. This works and provides reusabillity throughout the views and templates, but it would be nicer if there was possibility to generate route using Laravel's `route` helper function and just pass an `id` parameter from Handlebars context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you really need "bulletproof" solution for changing routes on frontend than most convenient solution is to make an accessor for route in your model. Something like this:

```
public function getRouteAttribute()
{
    return route('admin.membership.toggle-show-hide', ['id' => $this->id]);
}
```

Then you need to make sure that accessor is always available (even if you return JSON response) in your object instances using $appends property like this:

```
protected $appends = ['route'];
```

That should be it.

Comment: This is really nice solution which removes the need to worry about resource routes on the frontend (javascript). This way routes needed in Handlebars template are always available and valid. Thanks ;)

Answer (score 1):

In fact you can't use both JS and PHP variables/functions at the same time as JS variables may change over time during the PHP session.

When JS is involved I don't use routes, I use plain string routes like `data-route="'/admin/membership/toggle/' + id"`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I don't want to hardcode the route because route may change over time and then I would need to change 'string routes' in each Handlebars template and other places where that route is being used. Because of that I want to use Laravel's helper function `route` and just pass an `id` parameter as Handlebars expression ( `{{ id }}` is just a template expression and it works perfectly when it is not used within `route` helper or any other statement already wrapped in curly brackets).

Comment: Yep I understood your question but as I said it's not possible to use JS (Handlebar) variables in PHP function (Laravel `route()` for instance).

If you are afraid of changing routes (which really don't happen that much in a real project), you could always create a JS file where you register all your routes. In case you really change your routes, you'll have only 1 JS file to edit.

Comment: Few minutes ago, I updated my question with the alternative I currently use. Did you mean about something like that? It works really nice, but I wondered if there was some 'cleaner' way of doing this.

Comment: Yep something like that is clean enough. You should not worry too much about routes changing over time it really does not happen much often once you're in production

Comment: Thanks. I just wanted to take the advantage of Laravel's helper functions together with Handlebars template. I will take little more time to try finding some better solution than registering HB helpers, but as you said, maybe I should not worry too much about routes changing over time ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this sample code.

```
<a href=".URL::route('admin.membership.toggle-show-hide',[$id])." class="btn-blue">Hide</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution. Suddenly who needs
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aWY6u.png)

from

```
{{ route('admin.membership.toggle-show-hide', ['id' => @{{ id }}]) }}
```

to

```
<?php echo route('admin.membership.toggle-show-hide', ['id' => {{ id }}]) ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem in handlebars, I solved it using this solution

my problem:
`<button type="button" class="btn bg-orange btn-flat margin"><a href="{{ route('employee.purchases.show',[@{{ category_id }}]) }}"> View PO</a></button>`

to this:
`<button type="button" class="btn bg-orange btn-flat margin"> <a href="../purchases/@{{ category_id }}/show" target="_blank">View PO</a>  </button>`

make sure you have the routes declared in your web.php

Comment: Please format your code as code using the ``` code ``` feature.